# Header files em C++ usando mais de uma vez

Tags: c, header, gcc, mingw, c++14

Estou a desenvolver um projeto multiplataforma (Windows - Linux - MacOS). Durante o seu desenvolvimento e ao gerar documentação (via Doxygen) percebi que há muitos ficheiros `*.h` a serem chamados por vários ficheiros `*.cpp`. As minhas questões são as seguintes:

1. É possível limitar a quantidade de vezes que um *header* file é chamado no projeto?
2. Recomendam o uso da diretiva `#pragma once`?
3. Tendo por exemplo que o ficheiro `a.h` inclui `a1.h` e `a2.h` e é incluído por `b.h` e `b.h` necessita de `a1.h`, tenho de os chamar implicitamente em `b.h`? Não é suficiente estarem já chamados em `a.h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> É possível limitar a quantidade de vezes que um header file é chamado no projeto?

Sim, se a quantidade for 1. Mais que isso precisaria de ferramentas auxiliares, mas não faz sentido, não tem porque entrar 2 vezes.

> Recomendam o uso da directiva "#pragma once"?

Nos [compiladores que aceitam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), sim, eu prefiro o seu uso. Nem todos aceitam e preferem outros mecanismos que faça o mesmo. Acho preciosismo no estágio atual. Em geral programadores C ou C++ de verdade são acima da média, mas vejo muitos tendo essas coisas de seguir receita de bolo sem olhar o contexto.

> Tendo por exemplo que o ficheiro `a.h` inclui `a1.h` e `a2.h` e é incluído por `b.h` e `b.h` necessita de `a1.h`, tenho de os chamar implicitamente em `b.h`? Não é suficiente estarem já chamados em `a.h`?

Não precisa. Em condições normais ele já estará incluso e este é até o motivo de existir o `pragma once`. Você poderia incluir para garantir e não correr o risco de entrar duas vezes.

Dá para fazer umas maluquices e fazer com que a segunda entrada seja processada de forma diferente, mas não recomendo isso, ainda que tenha alguma utilidade.